# Find the least $x$ so that the fourth root of $(x+1)^4-x^4$ is integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As in the title, how to find the least $x$ so that $((x+1)^4-x^4)^{1/4}$ is integer where $x$ is an integer?

Thanks!

Comment: The title and body are consistent. "Fourth root of $(x+1)^4 - x^4$" is the same as "$((x+1)^4 - x^4)^{1/4}$". So I don't see any need for confusion (or for editing the title).

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane ok I didn't want the title to be too tall so I wrote the expression in words and now it's kindly fixed by naslundx

Comment: First version of title was wrong. So, is x also an integer? Are you trying to find an example for the last theorem of Fermat? $z^4=(x+1)^4=x^4+y^4$?

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be a positive integer, a positive real, or what?

Comment: @LutzL precisely

Comment: @LutzL: I have reverted the title to the first version, at least the first recorded version. In general I prefer not to edit the OP's words for minor reasons like change of notation, unless really necessary.

Comment: So you are sure that you can disprove Euler, Kummer and Wiles?

Comment: @LutzL my bad and the question should be closed?

Comment: Try $x=-1/2$. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @LutzL: If someone already knew everything, they wouldn't be asking here. :-) Surely the OP is not trying to disprove Euler / Kummer / Wiles; more likely the OP hasn't thought of these theorems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course $x=0$ works.

Can we go lower? If $x$ is large and negative, the expression is negative.

You will find also that $x=-0.5$ works, and you can't go lower, because the expression is then negative.

Note, we can write $(x+1)^4-x^4=\left((x+1)^2-x^2)\right)\left((x+1)^2+x^2)\right)=(2x+1)\left((x+1)^2+x^2)\right)$

This is $2x+1$ times a positive number, and is therefore negative when $2x+1$ is negative.

The question was not flawed - the least integer is $0$, the least real number is $-0.5$. The expression regarded as a function on the reals takes every non-negative integer value, so every integer fourth power.

Comment: thanks for answering my seriously flawed question...

Answer (score 2):

$x = 0$ is one such integer, because in that case $(x+1)^4 - x^4 = 1^4 - 0^4 = 1$, and its fourth root is $1$ which is again an integer.

No smaller integer $x$ is possible, because for the fourth root of $f(x) = (x+1)^4 - x^4$ to exist, $f(x)$ must be nonnegative, and the smallest possible nonnegative value $0$ is not possible (that would require $(x+1)^4 = x^4$, which has no integer solutions, though $x = -1/2$ is possible), and the next smallest possible value $1$ is what we have found.

(In fact, no larger integer $x$ is possible either, by the (relatively easy to prove) $n=4$ case of Fermat's last theorem.)